# Extract integer

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/ip/Asus-24-1920x1080-144Hz-1ms-DVI-HDMI-DP-AMD-FreeSync-HD-Gaming-Monitor-MG248QR/284736115')
c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

all=soup.find("div",{("class"):("hf-Bot")})
  for item in all:
print(item.find("h1",{"class":"prod-ProductTitle font-normal"}).text)
for item in all:
    print([item.find("span",{"class":"price-characteristic"}, {"itemprop": "price"})][0])

None
None
None
<span class="price-characteristic" content="269.99" itemprop="price">269</span>
None
None
None
```

I want to know how I can just exact the price of the item 269.99. I cant find a function to make it happen

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61497064/edit) your question to explain that row of None you printed?

Comment: Please approved editing. It looks like better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **scrape** `title` and `price` for single item. you can try it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/ip/Asus-24-1920x1080-144Hz-1ms-DVI-HDMI-DP-AMD-FreeSync-HD-Gaming-Monitor-MG248QR/284736115')
c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

all=soup.find("div",{("class"):("hf-Bot")})

price = soup.find('div', class_="prod-PriceHero")

print("Title : " + all.h1.text)
print("Price : " + price.span.span.span.span.text)
```

Output:

```
Title : Asus 24" 1920x1080 144Hz 1ms DVI HDMI DP AMD FreeSync HD Gaming Monitor - MG248QR
Price : $269.99
```